# Rails 4, is there a gem that validates a user is entering a real name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rubygems, names

I want to make sure that users enter real names for their profile on my website. Is there a gem that will take care of these validations?

Comment: How to you expect to judge the realness of a person's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot validate a name automatically. What's a real name? How do you define a real name?

The only way to validate identity is to ask for a photo ID and let a human verify it. This is even not a 100%, as there might be some Jason Bourne trying to use your system - so he's not using a "real" name either.

Also consider that there may be laws prohibiting or restring your from asking and storing Photo IDs of your users.

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes a name is purely subjective and thus is not deterministic unless the parameters are explicitly configured within some context. Given the amount of configuration needed to accomplish a task like this I doubt that a general purpose library could reasonably exist that would be little more than a wrapper around some gnarly regular expression. What you could do is write your own regular expression for detecting a real name. Two things will happen, you will learn a lot about regexes and computational theory, and you will create something which will inevitably generate both false positives and false negatives. However its your application so whats in a name is entirely up to you.